# Submit form string input is null in c#

Tags: javascript, c#

In my javascript I have:

```js
function reset() {
        document.getElementById("login").submit();
    }
```

The request then looks like:
[image]

I'm submitting that to .NET api:

```js
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Reset([FromBody]string login)
{}
```

and the `login` string is null. Is the request I am making wrong? Or am I accepting it wrong? I'd like to just send `abcdefr` instead of `login=abcdefr`

my html:

```html
<div id="reset_password_panel">
    <form name="reset-pasword" id="reset-pasword" action="/Reset" method="POST">
        <label for="user">User</label>
        <div><input style="width: 100%" type="text" placeholder="User" id="login" name="login" required />
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;margin-top: 10px;">
            <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px"><button id="btn_login" class="button" onclick="resetPassword()"
                    type="submit">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

If I create class:

```js
public class LoginModel {
  public string Login {get;set;}
}
```

and pass it to

```js
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Reset([FromBody]LoginModel login)
    {}
```

it works, but is it possible to pass *just a string*

Comment: Please use Developer Tools in Chrome to show us the **exact** URL and the exact **body** being submitted.

Comment: Is your `<form>` using POST or GET? Makes a real difference for how to get data from the request.

Comment: I am using POST method

Comment: So, right now, your `login` value server-side is `null`?

Comment: @mjwills  yes it is

Comment: I added some more information

Answer (score 1):

The request body is actually `login=abcdefr`, according to the screenshot, therefore you should declare a class to accept it. If you want to *only* send a string, consider sending `"abcdefr"`:

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': '/Reset',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'data': JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("login").value),
    'dataType': 'json'
});
```

Then you can accept it with a string.

Answer (score 0):

> it works, but is it possible to pass *just a string*

You can pass raw string data to your route, provided the content type is `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and the parameter type is `string`; anything else and it won't match your route.

If your parameter is a model, the model binder will try to map the input (whether JSON or form data) to your model. If it's a string, it will pass you the raw data.

The problem is, that if you are passing in raw form data, you'll just have to parse out the bits you want (in your case the "login" value) anyway, so you may as well just use a model instead, and let the model binder do it for you.